# IIS URL Rewrite - add query string var depending on domain

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting

Using the IIS url rewrite module for IIS 7, is it possible to accomplish the following:

I have 2 domains, domain1.com and domain2.com.  Both domains represent two different but very closely linked events for our company.  So I would like the users to manage the site data from the same CMS.

So basically:

domain1.com and domain2.com refer to the same index.php and depending on the QS parameters, the user is presented the content for the respective event. So my index.php would take the following qs:

> index.php?site=event1&lang=en&route=home

What i would like would be that:

> domain1.com/en/home
>
> would refer to:
>
> index.php?site=event1&lang=en&route=home

and

> domain2.com/en/home
>
> would refer to:
>
> index.php?site=event2&lang=en&route=home

It would be like iis url rewrite would append the site parameter with a value based on the domain.

is this possile?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this IIS Rewrite rule to your web.config:

```html
<rule name="domain1.com" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^en/home" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(domain1.com|www.domain1.com)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.domain1.com/index.php?site=event1&lang=en&route=home" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
<rule name="domain2.com" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^en/home" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(domain2.com|www.domain2.com)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.domain2.com/index.php?site=event2&lang=en&route=home" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

These rules basically say:

1. Match any request for /en/home
2. For the domain1.com or www.domain1.com
3. Rewrite the user to the correct site/event

Comment: You shouldn't need the `http://www.domain1.com/` and `http://www.domain2.com/` parts in the rewrite action.